# How can I count the number of rows returned?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

```
myDB = pymysql.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="exampleuser",
  password="examplepassword",
  database="exampledb"
)

myCursor = myDB.cursor()
msg = "something"
SQL = "SELECT * FROM `example` WHERE `example`='" + msg + "'"
myCursor.execute(SQL)
myResult = myCursor.fetchall()
```

Some times it can return multiple results. So, I do not think `fetchone` will work.

How can I count the number of rows in Python?, like in PHP, I could use `mysqli_num_rows()`.

I am unable to find any way to do this. I am using Python 3.

I am absolutely new to python MySQL. I am really familiar with MySQL in PHP.

You can do it with `len()`. But, for my curiosity: is there way to do it using pymysql directly?

Comment: @Dharman, is there another way? `len()` can be useful. But, still... is there a way in pymysql?

Comment: @Dharman, not talking about caching at all. Only wanting to see if no rows were returned.

Comment: @Dharman, why does `mysqli_num_rows` work in PHP if mysql doesn't return such info?

Comment: Either way, I have to warn you to never concatenate variables into the SQL query. Use parameters instead. It is the second argument to `myCursor.execute(SQL)`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the number of rows returned without calling `len` on the resultset you can inspect the cursor's [rowcount](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#rowcount) attribute.

```py
myCursor = myDB.cursor()
msg = "something"
SQL = "SELECT * FROM `example` WHERE `example`= %s"
myCursor.execute(SQL, (msg,))
print('Number of rows is', myCursor.rowcount)
```

Comment: It only returns the number of rows 'affected' right? So SELECT statements won't be working with it right?

Comment: It works fine for `SELECT`: from the linked definition: "number of rows that the last .execute*() produced (for DQL statements like SELECT) "

Comment: `rowcount` only gives a non-zero answer if you call `cursor.fetchall()` before accessing it.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 3 ways to get this information:

- The `execute()` method returns the number of rows affected for DML statements and the number of rows fetched for DQL statements.
- The same information will also be stored in a read-only property `rowcount`.
- If you want to know how many elements you have in your list you can use `len()` to count the elements.

```
myCursor = myDB.cursor()
msg = "something"
numRows = myCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `example` WHERE `example`= %s", [msg])
myResult = myCursor.fetchall()
print(numRows, myCursor.rowcount, len(myResult))
```

Answer (score 2):

To count a large number of rows from a database, never use the `len()` function because it requires you to use `cursor.fetchall` and then count. That's just a waste of resources. Use `SELECT COUNT (*)` **to have the server do the counting**.

You may not come across demanding sets as a beginner, but over time, you will need to have a more demanding condition, that you will need to `join` with other tables.
Also, it is possible to work with multiple databases, in which case it is easiest to use as I wrote `SELECT COUNT (*)`.

The solution is applicable to the vast majority of databases.

```py
sql = "SELECT * FROM `example` WHERE `example`='" + msg + "'"
sql_count = f"select count(*) from ({sql}) as table"
```

In this case, the database calculates the number of rows of any sql.

Sometimes (for example `DB2`) you will have to use, `uncommitted read` option allows an application to read while acquiring few locks, at the risk of reading uncommitted data. UR isolation applies only to the following read-only operations: SELECT, SELECT INTO, or FETCH from a read-only result table.

```py
sql = '''
    SELECT * FROM
    Table1
    INNER JOIN / JOIN
    Table2
    ON join condition
    [WHERE] with ur;'''

# or specifically

sql = '''
    SELECT * FROM
    employee_details JOIN
    contact_details ON
    employee_details.employee_id = contact_details.employee_id with ur;'''
```

Using `with ur` on the end of a query tells `DB2` that you want to use the `Uncommitted Read` isolation level.

In that case, counting the lines will require you to throw out `with ur` and give it at the end of the initial solution, that ie `SELECT COUNT (*)`.

Here, the solution was solved by replacing it `with ur` from the initial sql and added it to the end of the final sql, ie the sqlthat will count the rows.

```py
sql = '''
    SELECT * FROM
    employee_details JOIN
    contact_details ON
    employee_details.employee_id = contact_details.employee_id'''

count_sql = f"select count(*) from ({sql}) as table with ur;"
```

If the program will decide automatically in relation to the number of rows, then you can also write a function that would now generate it and replace it for you. E.g:

```py
def generate_sql_count(sql):
    with_ur, with_ur_ = "WITH UR;", "WITH UR"
    sql = " ".join(str(sql).split()).upper()
    if with_ur in sql:
        sql = sql.replace(with_ur, '')
    elif with_ur_ in sql:
        sql = sql.replace(with_ur_, '')
    sql_count = f"select count(*) from ({sql}) as table with ur;"
    return sql_count


sql = '''
    SELECT * FROM
    employee_details JOIN
    contact_details ON
    employee_details.employee_id = contact_details.employee_id with ur;'''

sql_count = generate_sql_count(sql)
print(sql_count)
```

- output:

```sql
select count(*) from (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_DETAILS JOIN CONTACT_DETAILS ON EMPLOYEE_DETAILS.EMPLOYEE_ID = CONTACT_DETAILS.EMPLOYEE_ID ) as table with ur;
```

Good tutorial on Concurrency and Isolation Levels (one of the most failed areas on the certification exams): http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/tutorials/db2-cert6106/index.html
You can also look at exactly what interests you, ie.
[Build a custom web application with IBM Cloud, PHP, and MySQL](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/cl-track-time-on-projects-with-ibm-cloud-1/)

It would be solved in a similar way from other databases.
I hope it was helpful.