# How to add an error message if the name entered is not in the table

Tags: python, sql-server

```
def search_by_name(self):
    query = """SELECT * FROM Books WHERE book_name = ?"""
    self.Name = input("Enter The Book Name:")
    cursor.execute(query, self.Name)
    for row in cursor:
        print(row)
```

this function retrieve a book info from the database based on the name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I count the number of rows returned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66505179/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-rows-returned)

Comment: How? you write some code to determine if the query retrieved any rows. Hmm I wonder if there is an attribute (hint) that contains that information?